# IF Statement = List

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need an IF statement that equals to a list.  I have public holidays on a list named "PublicHolidayWorked".  If the date on a timesheet equals to the list of public holidays then give me what is in Column O else 0.00. So what I've done is `=IF(D2=PublicHolidayWorked,O2,0.00)` but it doesn't work correct.

Comment: what exactly should D2 equal ? show some examples of data

Comment: Equal to the list? Or do you mean the item is contained within the list?

Comment: D2= to list of public holidays.  The list name is PublicHolidayWorked

Comment: How do I add a screenshot?

Comment: You can [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1272027/edit) your question

Comment: `it doesn't work correct.` If you had a customer say that to you, would you understand the issue? If not, then guess what? Niether do we!!

Answer (score 2):

Comparing a single value to a list results in an array of `TRUE/FALSE` values, not a single `TRUE/FALSE` result, so to get the answer that way you have to do something with the resultant array, better to use `COUNTIF` like this:

`=IF(COUNTIF(PublicHolidayWorked,D2),O2,0)`

Answer (score 0):

I've replicated and it works fine

The issue is that what you've written probably doesn't actually work as you need to use strings! meaning quote marks!

```
=IF(D2=PublicHolidayWorked,O2,0.00)
```

should result in an error with `#NAME?`

```
=IF(D2="PublicHolidayWorked",O2,0.00)
```

Comment: I've tried now with the " before and after list name but still doesn't work.  How can I send a screenshot?

Comment: Upload your screenshot to imgur.com and edit your question to include the link to the screenshot.